# Finding the number of order-preserving functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Given partial orders (A, R) and (B, S), a function f : A → B is called orderpreserving
if for all $x, y ∈ A, xRy ⇒ f(x)Sf(y)$. How many such order-preserving
functions are for each of the following, where $R, S$ both denote ≤ (the usual "less
than or equal to" relation)?

a) A = {1, 2, 3, 4}, B = {1, 2};

...

I'm not sure I understand this question. So any function where f(x) ≤ f(y) and f(x), f(y) ∈ {1,2} should be counted? Well, that number is infinite: f(x) = x/x, 2x/2x, 3x/3x... etc etc

Comment: $f(x)=\frac xx$ and $f(x)=\frac{2x}{2x}$ are not two different functions, just two (quite roundabout) ways of describing the _same_ function, namely the one that maps each of $1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ to $1$.

Comment: Remember that two functions $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ are the same if for every $x \in X,\ f(x) = g(x)$. This means that although there could be many ways of defining the function $f(x) = 1$ as you've done above, they're all the same function.